# Socket connection problems over internet C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I made a program using the socket class in C# which is a chat program. In LAN network I can work with it, but over the internet, I can't.
Can you guide me?

I want to send the medium files (from 10MB to 500M) between some computers and what I have to do to Connect to some computer with this app from the Internet?
here my code

```
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint elocal, eremote;
    byte[] buffer;
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        textBox1.Text = textBox3.Text = getip();
    }  
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text));
        sck.Bind(elocal);
        eremote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox3.Text), Convert.ToInt16(textBox4.Text));
        sck.Connect(eremote);
        buffer = new byte[1500];
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref eremote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
    }
    private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] recive = new byte[1500];
            recive = (byte[])res.AsyncState;
            ASCIIEncoding aend = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string mes = aend.GetString(recive);
            listBox1.Items.Add("other : " + mes);
            buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref eremote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding aend = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] send = new byte[1500];
        send = aend.GetBytes(textBox5.Text);
        sck.Send(send);
        listBox1.Items.Add("you : " + textBox5.Text);
        textBox5.Text = "";
    }
    private string getip()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ip.ToString());
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                return ip.ToString();
        }
        return "0.0.0.0";
    }
```

and when I want to connect a computer with global IP it shows me this error
[image: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 200.254.57.70:20]

guys look at my code at Form_Load, the AddressFamily is inner network, I have to change it to what ,to make connection over the internet?

Comment: "can't" means what, exactly? We have no idea what particular difficulties you're experiencing, there could be any number of potential issues. Describe the problem(s) you're having specifically and in enough detail for someone to help you - e.g. providing error messages, debugging info, network logs etc. etc. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more guidance on asking the kind of questions which enable people to provide useful answers.

Comment: P.S. as a general guess / assumption...the obvious environmental difference between going across a LAN and going across the internet is usually the existence of firewalls (and/or other forms of gateway server), particularly at the boundaries between local LAN and public internet. So maybe you need some ports opening or something somewhere in the route. But that's just a guess - as I said, you provided no information about the actual problem, or about the network topology between the machines you're trying to connect, so currently we can only speculate.

Comment: ok When through different networks (internet) I want to connect to another computer , its show me an error, it's this IP Does not exist

Comment: ok. Are you by any chance using the local IP of the remote computer? (I mean, local to the LAN  where that remote computer is located?). Do you understand what NAT (Network Address Translation) is, what it does, and the potential difference between a public and local IP address? And, even if you switch to using that machine's public IP address, if there is a firewall and/or NAT enabled then you still won't be able to connect without the necessary port(s) being opened/forwarded on the firewall/router/gateway device(s).

Comment: P.S. _what_ shows you the error? Can you show us the line which throws the error, and provide the proper full error message and stack trace, please. Like I said, please be specific and detailed. Also, your question has an "edit" button (below the blue tags), so please use that to update your post with any new information, rather than burying it in these comments. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest though,if you just want to transmit some files, I'd be using a ready-made FTP or SFTP server, or using a free account on a sync service such as Dropbox or Google Drive. Writing your own raw socket server to transmit files is like going back in time 30 years. Unless you're doing this for a piece of homework specifically to learn how raw sockets work, then you're really making pointless extra work for yourself - just use an existing tool which is already designed for this purpose. Often these services are scriptable if you need to automate the transfers or something.

Comment: Equally if you want to make a chat app, I'd use a simple web application with websockets as the intermediary. That could also be used for file transfers as well if you wanted it to, although maybe not ideal for larger files. Then you generally don't have to worry about firewalls etc. That's how most applications of this type are structured nowadays (except maybe real-time games and so on, but that's a whole different genre of application with totally different requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, error messages are text. A picture of an error is not much use, it can't be copied/pasted/googled easily. Also that isn't the full stack trace as requested, and doesn't tell us which line throws the error. Please provide the full information I requested. I note that your `catch` block discards all information except the basic message. This a coding mistake - it's fine to display limited info on the screen, but you need to log the rest of it elsewhere (e.g. into a file) otherwise you're just making it impossible for you to debug your own code properly.

Comment: What did you type in the text boxes?

Comment: P.S. The `:20` at the end of the error message looks wrong. A valid IPv4 address looks like this `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. It doesn't have `:xx` on the end. What was that supposed to be?

Comment: :20 is the port, the Socket class writes the IP and port together and then sends the request like this  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20

Comment: Ok. So again, we need the full error message and stack trace. Why the delay in giving that info?

Comment: you know, by default,  web socket is just in Lan network, my question is how to change the code I provided to work over the Internet
It is quite clear that in this code if I use global IP, it shows me an error

Comment: Yes that is quite clear, it's true. But I already suggested some possible reasons for that, and you have no response. We can't fix problems where you do not have any clues.

Comment: working over the internet isn't a case of changing the code - technically it's still a TCP/IP network, there is no difference in that way. The problem is likely to be related to firewalls etc, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to review my code and question
I'm sorry if my questions are not clear, but I uploaded the program with the source and you can see this error for yourself [https://drive.google.com/file/d/16KohWZ0SD2nsPVzcg4LdAeHzG3GdAhVz/view?usp=sharing](this link)

Comment: Why can't you just tell us the full error message and stack trace? That would be much easier. Do you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: And also I may or may not experience the same problem, because I may not have the same network setup as you. Again, you still haven't explained anything about that either, despite being asked more than once. Again, do you understand what I'm asking for?

Comment: I swear to God I understand what you are saying, but the error text is really short, it's "The entered IP is not acceptable" or sometimes "IP not found" I never got a firewall error And I gave all the permissions to the program and the firewall is off,

Comment: There should be a stack trace behind it showing exactly which line threw the error. If you're not seeing that then you're not logging or displaying exceptions correctly. If you step through the code with the debugger in visual studio then you'd definitely be able to see all the details

Comment: As for firewall errors, you don't get a specific message about that. A firewall doesn't alert you to its presence specifically. It simply closes off ports or even whole routes, which can then result in your computer being unable to locate a specific IP address and/or being unable to connect to a specific port on a remote machine. That's why you need to have some idea of the design of the network between the two machines, so you've got some idea what obstacles might be in the way. It's a bit like looking at a real map to find out if there's a bridge over the river or not.

Comment: "The firewall is off"... Which firewall exactly? The firewall on the computer itself is only one of many possible obstacles.